# Is there a way to CC a copy of an email which is already sent?

Tags: gmail

I've sent an email to `A@company.com` and I would like to CC the email to `B@company.com`.

However, I've forgotten to CC a copy to `B@company.com`. If I resend another email to `A@company.com` and CC it to `B@company.com`, `A@company.com` would have received two emails from me.

Is there a way to CC a copy of an email which is already sent?

Comment: You forward the email you sent to A@company.com to B@company.com. There is no other option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do it. The first email you sent out will never know about the 2nd email. Even if there is a way to recall the first email, recalled emails never work flawlessly.

The only option: think of something new to add to the chain, then forward it to both A and B. It could be as simple as saying that you are adding B to the CC line. Using forward makes sure the newest email has any attachments that were on the first email.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the part on "recalling emails"?

Comment: Some email systems, like MS Exchange, have the ability to pull an email back. Sometime the recipient has no idea it was recalled, other times the are sent a message saying it is being recalled. If the recipient has already read the message it does no good. Gmail doesn't have this feature.

Comment: This is a proprietary feature, The SMTP/POP3/IMAP standards don't allow for such thing. Besides MS Exchange, you may want to check these guys out: http://www.bigstring.com/

Comment: Also, message recalling requires both parties to use the same mailing system (i.e. if your company uses MS Exchange & your external recipient doesn't, you won't be able to recall the message).